# How to Extract LGBM Model Rules of Prediction (Coefficients)

Tags: lightgbm

How can I extract LightGBM model coefficients, rules of prediction by features? I am in insurance industry. This is absolutely necessary for strict regulatory requirements. Something like a set of rules like: "if feature 1 and feature 2 and feature 3 then y_pred = 104.62" would work.

Many thanks!

Philip W.

Example Codes:

```py
import time 
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.metrics import d2_tweedie_score

tweedie_p = 1.50568
mono_constraints = (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

s_time = time.time()
print("Starting the LightGBM training")

params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting': 'gbdt',
    'num_leaves': 174,
    'max_depth': 11,
    'n_jobs': 6,
    'n_estimators': 1000,
    'subsample_for_bin': 200000,
    'learning_rate': 0.06308264944407528,
    'random_state': seed2,
    'min_gain_to_split': 9.540907629434999,
    'min_data_in_leaf': 1800,
    'bagging_fraction': 1.00,  
    'bagging_seed': 49,
    'bagging_freq': 1,  
    'feature_fraction': 1.00,
    'feature_fraction_seed': 1958,
    'extra_trees': True,
    'extra_seed': 1975,
    'lambda_l1': 70,
    'lambda_l2': 0,
    'importance_type': 'gain',
    # 'init_model': model_saved,
    'monotone_constraints': mono_constraints,
    'monotone_constraints_method': 'advanced'
}

mdl = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    **params,
    objective='tweedie',
    tweedie_variance_power=tweedie_p
)

mdl.fit(
    X_train, y_train, sample_weight=w_train,
    eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid), (X_train, y_train)],
    eval_sample_weight=[w_valid, w_train],
    eval_metric=['auc', 'tweedie'],
    callbacks=[lgb.early_stopping(40)]
    )

y_pred = mdl.predict(X_valid, num_iteration=mdl.best_iteration_)
d2_score = d2_tweedie_score(y_valid, y_pred, sample_weight=w_valid, power=tweedie_p)

run_time = round(time.time() - s_time, 3)
print(f"Fit_time = {run_time}")      # Fit_time = 7.203

print(f"Best_iteration = {mdl.best_iteration_}")  # best_iteration = 56

print(f"Best_score = {mdl.best_score_}")
print(f"\td2_tweedie_score: {d2_score:.5f}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightGBM model training creates an ensemble of decision trees.

When predicting for one sample, the sample is passed through each tree, and then all of the trees' outputs are added to produce a final prediction.

So LightGBM models do not have "coefficients" in the way that something like a linear model might.

There are several ways to inspect the structure of those trees in `lightgbm`, the LightGBM Python package. For example, given that you've trained a regression model in Python 3.10, using `lightgbm==4.0.0`, as follows...

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1_000)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(data=X, label=y)

bst = lgb.train(
    train_set=dtrain,
    params={
        "objective": "regression",
        "min_data_per_leaf": 3,
        "num_iterations": 10
    }
)
```

... you could do the following to obtain the model structure.

#### Option 1: dump model to a `pandas` DataFrame

```py
bst.trees_to_dataframe().head(10)
```

```
   tree_index  node_depth node_index left_child right_child parent_index split_feature  split_gain  threshold decision_type missing_direction missing_type      value  weight  count
0           0           1       0-S0       0-S1        0-S2         None     Column_79   5864870.0   0.053069            <=              left         None  -1.711640     0.0   1000
1           0           2       0-S1       0-S3        0-S6         0-S0     Column_23   2577040.0   0.319818            <=              left         None  -9.143480   515.0    515
2           0           3       0-S3      0-S11        0-S7         0-S1     Column_88   1499690.0  -0.403728            <=              left         None -14.462300   329.0    329
3           0           4      0-S11       0-L0       0-S15         0-S3     Column_79    375834.0  -1.545806            <=              left         None -23.199700   123.0    123
4           0           5       0-L0       None        None        0-S11          None         NaN        NaN          None              None         None -37.494507    16.0     16
5           0           5      0-S15      0-L12       0-S29        0-S11     Column_80    303124.0   0.047732            <=              left         None -21.062200   107.0    107
6           0           6      0-L12       None        None        0-S15          None         NaN        NaN          None              None         None -26.434711    53.0     53
7           0           6      0-S29      0-L16       0-L30        0-S15     Column_22    132407.0  -0.607386            <=              left         None -15.789200    54.0     54
8           0           7      0-L16       None        None        0-S29          None         NaN        NaN          None              None         None -22.245471    20.0     20
9           0           7      0-L30       None        None        0-S29          None         NaN        NaN          None              None         None -11.991366    34.0     34
```

#### Option 2: dump model to JSON format

```py
bst.dump_model()["tree_info"]
```

```json
{"tree_index": 0, "num_leaves": 31, "num_cat": 0, "shrinkage": 1, "tree_structure":
{"split_index": 0, "split_feature": 79, "split_gain": 5864870, "threshold": 0.0530686,
"decision_type": "<=", "default_left": true, "missing_type": "None", 
"internal_value": -1.71164, "internal_weight": 0, "internal_count": 1000, 
"left_child": {"split_index": 1, "split_feature": 23, "split_gain": 2577040, 
"threshold": 0.31981814026944827, "decision_type": "<=",
"default_left": true, "missing_type": "None",
...
```

#### Option 3: plot one tree at a time

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot third tree (just as an example)
ax = lgb.plot_tree(gbm, tree_index=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: a decision tree with feature names in the nodes and decisions on the edges]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my questions, James!!! I will explore these. BTW, I trained my model using LGBMRegressor. I thought the prediction was using best_iteration. Is that right?

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted so others coming here will understand that this solves the question.

> I thought the prediction was using `best_iteration`

That depends on how you've trained the model. You didn't specify if you're using e.g. R, Python, the CLI, etc. In the Python package, if `best_iteration` is populated then by default all the trees up to that iteration are used to create predictions in `Booster.predict()` ([code link](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/7d4d897566b9650a8dad5294f335fb4d144d6848/python-package/lightgbm/basic.py#L4159-L4163)).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I should have included more details. I added the python code for clarity.